# Run CSS inside JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some problems with my webpage. I have four different images which are grayscaled using CSS. I have created an .svg file to make this possible. Now what I want is whenever the user clicks the image the grayscale filter will be disabled, showing the original colors. But the css has only :active and :hover. What I want is during click. Here's my code:

```
//CSS
<style type="text/css">
 #main, #beverage, #set, #appetizer {
filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}
#main {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

//IMAGES
<td>
<img src="main.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="main"><br>
<img src="beverage.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="beverage"><br>
<img src="set.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="set"><br>
<img src="set.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="appetizer"><br>
</td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply set up a class with the grayscale filter and remove it when the image is clicked

**HTML**

```
<img src="main.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="main" class="grayscale"><br>
<img src="beverage.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="beverage" class="grayscale"><br>
<img src="set.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="set" class="grayscale"><br>
<img src="set.png" width="80" style="cursor:pointer" id="appetizer" class="grayscale"><br>
```

**CSS**

```
.grayscale {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.grayscale').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('grayscale');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').css('key' , 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the CSS in the click handler:

```
$("#main, #beverage, #set, #appetizer").click(function() {
    $(this).css({ filter: "none",
                  "-webkit-filter": "grayscale(0)"
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.#main, img#beverage, img#set, img#appetizer').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-filter': '',
        'filter': ''
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keep z-index also with this class for more perfect work without any future errors:

.grayscale {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
    z-index:100;
}
and then use click function :

$('.grayscale').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('grayscale');
});
```